# Insert delayed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to do? there is an active record option?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Your question can be misleading.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using rails monkey patch:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.insert_low_priority(hash)
    keys = hash.keys.map { |v| "`#{v}`" }.join(',')
    values = hash.values.map { |v| sanitize(v) }.join(',')
    connection.insert_sql("INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO `#{table_name}` (#{keys}) VALUES(#{values})")
  end
end
```

Add it to the initializers, e.g. config/initializers/activerecord_insert_low_priority.rb

Usage is simple: `ModelName.insert_low_priority :column1 => 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL also provides "INSERT DELAYED" which behaves a little differently from "LOW PRIORITY" I believe?